# Java + Spring MVC + Hibernate Persistence Error - Cant Persist User

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, maven

Ok so I am building an ecommerce site using java spring mvc, spring security, maven, hibernate, and some other technologies however those should be the only ones relevant to my problem. I am doing all java config with no XML by the way (which I am currently considering revising since I am running into situations where xml just seems easier).

I would like to know why I am getting an no exceptions upon maven install but getting exceptions on server restart (tomcat 7).

I have tried to get this down to as simple as possible while still having a user and a role.  When I am looking at the code, it really is pretty straight forward stuff - I am dying to find out why it errors out everytime.

Main Appconfig class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.crutchsf.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
    builder
        .scanPackages("com.crutchsf.users.model")
        .addProperties(getHibernateProperties());

    return builder.buildSessionFactory(); 
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    prop.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

    return prop;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {

    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
    ds.setUsername("bobby");
    ds.setPassword("password");
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager txManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
}

@Bean
public UserService userService() {

    UserService userService = new MyUserDetailsService();
    userService.setUserDao(new UserDaoImpl());
    return userService;
}

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("validation");
    return messageSource;
}   

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

 public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
        .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");    
}
}
```

User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "test")
public class User {

private Integer user_id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String passwordConf;

public User() {
}


public User(String username, String password) {

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}


@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
@GeneratedValue
public Integer getUserId() {
    return this.user_id;
}

@Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 60)
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Transient
public String getPasswordConf() {
    return this.passwordConf;
}

public void setPasswordConf(String passwordConf) {
    this.passwordConf = passwordConf;
}

}
```

UserRole class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles", catalog = "test", 
uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
    columnNames = { "role", "username" }))
public class UserRole{

private Integer userRoleId;
private User user;
private String role;

public UserRole() {
}

public UserRole(User user, String role) {
    this.user = user;
    this.role = role;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_role_id", 
    unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getUserRoleId() {
    return this.userRoleId;
}

public void setUserRoleId(Integer userRoleId) {
    this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
}

public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getRole() {
    return this.role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

}
```

UserDao Interface

```
public interface UserDao {

User findByUserName(String username);
List<User> findAllUsers();
void addUser(User user);

}
```

UserDaoImpl

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public User findByUserName(String username) {

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where username=?").setParameter(0, username)
            .list();

    if (users.size() > 0) {
        return users.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

 @Override
 @Transactional
 public void addUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(user);           

 }
```

UserService Interface

```
public interface UserService {

UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
void setUserDao(UserDao userDao);
void addUser(com.crutchsf.model.users.User user);
}
```

User Service Impl

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService, UserService {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;


@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.crutchsf.model.users.User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());

    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

}

private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.crutchsf.model.users.User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;
}   

@Override
@Transactional
public void addUser(com.crutchsf.model.users.User user) {
    this.userDao.addUser(user);
}

public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}

}
```

Database SQL used

```
CREATE  TABLE users (
user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id));
```

Ok I shortened this quite a bit to the simple task of persisting a user.  I cant get the server to startup without errors.  There has to be something wrong in the code above.

In AppConfig.java if I change the line "scanPackages...." to the actual class name

```
com.crutchsf.users.model.User
```

then my server starts up fine but when it reaches the line in my userDao to be persisted

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(user);
```

I get a different error from hibernate "Cant find entity com.crutchsf.users.model.User"

Here is the main error I get. Basically I can choose which error I want to get now.

```
    [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.crutchsf.config.AppConfig.sessionFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

thank you

Comment: Sorry for my question not being clear enough, I would like to know why I get errors/exceptions when I try to start my server before even running my project.  I dont know how to be clearer? That is why I put up all the code I have including stack trace - what else do I need? thank you

Comment: I think you actually need to post *less*. Right now, it's a huge dump of code. Your question should be [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that others don't have to read through irrelevant code to help you. Also, creating an MCVE example could lead to a solution found by yourself, as you're forced to isolate the problem.

Comment: Ok I see your point, I did read the rules before posting - I posted all the code to because i knew it has to be in there somewhere - I will work on trimming it up to not include so much content. thank you

Comment: I personally still find it too verbose, but others may disagree. But you have obviously made a effort to improve your post, and it's indeed better now. And, although it's lengthy, it's well structured, and the problem is IMO obvious enough. I have voted for reopening, as have two other users … let's see if you can get two more to vote in your favour. ;)

Comment: By the way, if you're getting a new error now (as posted in a comment below), maybe you write a new question concentrating on that error (post a stack trace etc.), and close/delete this one.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope it gets reopened.

Comment: Edited again, I think this is as simple as it can get while still having a user and a role.

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, this doesn't appear to be anything to do with Spring MVC or Hibernate.

The error message is:

> Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.crutchsf.config.AppConfig.sessionFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

If you have a stacktrace, you'll be able to see exactly what line the null reference occurred on.  If not, you'll have to fire up a debugger (or insert `println` statements) to find out.

Either way, it appears that your `AppConfig` class has a bug in it, or you are not initialising it correctly.  Look at the `sessionConfig()` method to see why it NPEs, and ensure that the appropriate references are not null before calling it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick resposne! Ok I fired up the debugger and set a break point on the return line of the sessionFactory() method of my AppConfig class and it does not error out, when I choose the "step into" option it brings me to a white screen (where the code would usually be) and it says "Source not found." in red letters, with an option to "Edit source lookup path" which brings me to a spring dialog popup box asking if I want to add or remove source lookup path. Thank you

Comment: I think this error was due to an autowire I had in my service class that shouldnt have been there, getting a new error now.